# Comparing between several fields and a table

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I've got the next to tables: Drugs, and Clients:

```
 idNum      | drugName  
 118        | drug1    
 118        | drug2   
 120        | drug1       
 120        | drug2       
 120        | drug3  
 121        | drug1       
 121        | drug3  
 122        | drug2
```

Clients:

```
idNum   |   Name     |   lastName   |
 118    |   name1    |     last1    |
 119    |   name2    |     last2    |
 120    |   name3    |     last3    |
 121    |   name4    |     last4    | 
 122    |   name5    |     last5    |
```

I want to create a new table containing all id's, Names and last names of clients who took the same drugs as client with the idNum='118'

Which means i need to get a table with only '120'.

So far i've got:

```
SELECT Clients.idNum,firstName, lastName   
FROM Clients, Drugs
WHERE Drugs.idNum=Clients.idNum
AND Clients.idNum<>'118' 
AND Clients.idNum IN 
(Select idNum From Drugs Where drugName IN 
(Select  drugName from Drugs where idNum='118'))
```

But this gives me also 121 and 122.
I guess 'IN' is something like 'Exists', So if someone has only 1 of the drugs the condition is enough. How do i actually compare between a table which i get from here:

```
  (Select  drugName from Drugs where idNum='118')
```

to a field in 'Drugs'?

Or maybe, How do i create a table for each of the customers and then compare it with the table?

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky query.  The idea is to generate the list of drugs for each client that matches client 118.  This is the "master" list.  Then, use `left outer join` to bring in the actual drugs for each client.  When a match fails, then filter out the client:

```
select master.idNum, master.firstName, master.lastName
from (select d.drugName, c.*
      from Drugs d cross join
           Clients c
      where d.idnum = 118
     ) master left outer join
     Drugs d
     on master.drugName = d.drugName and
        master.idNum = d.idNum
group by master.idNum, master.firstName, master.lastName
having count(d.drugName) = count(master.drugName);
```

The SQL Fiddle is [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/095a0/11).  If you want to additionally filter out client 118, then change the nested where clause to something like `d.idnum = 118 and c.idnum <> 118`.

You should also learn proper join syntax and the use of table aliases.

Comment: Thanks, But this answer still gives me 121 and 122. And it's not what i need.